# Aggregating and summing values from an object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to create an algorithm that can aggregate my objects key:value pair into a new object by filtering and summing  values
I would like to have the names filtered so they only aggregate once, for example there may be multiple `ana-json-to-parquet` values. The `count` key is the number of successes, failures, etc in a given `proc_nm`

1. filter proc names(postgres-loader, ana-json-to-parquet, etc)
2. filter status(success, fail, fatal, warning, etc)
3. sum count per status for proc names

so an example result would be

```
ana-json-to-parquet: {
  success: 500
  fail:523
  fatal:0
  ... 
  ...
},
postgres-loader: {
  success: 2313
  fail: 2131
  fatal: 1
  ... 
  ...
},
```

example of the data object:

```
{
proc_nm: ana-json-to-parquet
count:2
date:2021-11-04 00:00:00
status:warning
},
{
proc_nm: ana-json-to-parquet
count:50
date:2021-11-04 00:00:00
status:fatal
},
```

there are multiple proc_names and I am aware the dates are for the same hour, they are queried by hour so within the hour there may be multiple entries of the same proc_names with different statuses and counts

attempts: I can sum the counts per proc_nm, and I stored the data in a new object, but in this case I would like to create an object for every proc_nm and aggregate the counts per proc_nm and status

```
const data = datastream.rows
var results = {};
var totals = {};
for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
                    var o = data[d];
                    var proc = o["proc_nm"];
                    var values = results[proc] || {};
                    // Since the column names may change, we need to loop over the object
                    for (var key in o) {
                        // remove the undeeded keys
                        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.toLowerCase() != "proc_nm" && key.toLowerCase() != "date_trunc") {
                            // Now find the entry in the values obj that matches
                            var column = values[key] || 0;
                            // And the corresponding entry in the totals object
                            var totalsColumn = totals[key] || 0;
                            column += parseFloat(o[key]);
                            totalsColumn += parseFloat(o[key]);
                            values[key] = column;
                            totals[key] = totalsColumn;
                        }
                    }
                    results[proc] = values;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Ramda.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of its authors.)  Using Ramda, I would do this as a sequence of transformations:

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum} = R

const extract = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('proc_nm')),
  map (groupBy (prop ('status'))),
  map (map (pluck ('count'))),
  map (map (sum))
) 

const data = [{proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 26, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 73, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "fatal"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 34, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "success"}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

You can see what each step does by simply commenting out the subsequent ones.  You can play with this in the [Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?console%20.clear%20%28%29%0A%0Aconst%20extract%20%3D%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20groupBy%20%28prop%20%28%27proc_nm%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28groupBy%20%28prop%20%28%27status%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28map%20%28pluck%20%28%27count%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28map%20%28sum%29%29%0A%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-json-to-parquet%22%2C%20count%3A%202%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2000%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22warning%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-json-to-parquet%22%2C%20count%3A%2050%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2000%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22success%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-foobar%22%2C%20count%3A%2026%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2001%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22success%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-json-to-parquet%22%2C%20count%3A%2073%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2001%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22success%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-json-to-parquet%22%2C%20count%3A%2050%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2002%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22warning%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-foobar%22%2C%20count%3A%202%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2002%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22fatal%22%7D%2C%20%7Bproc_nm%3A%20%22ana-foobar%22%2C%20count%3A%2034%2C%20date%3A%20%222021-11-04%2002%3A%2000%3A%2000%22%2C%20status%3A%20%22success%22%7D%5D%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28extract%20%28data%29%29).

But those Ramda helper functions are pretty easy to write on our own.  We can write and maintain our own versions of these:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (arg) =>
  fns .reduce ((a, fn) => fn (a), arg)
const prop = (s) => (o) => 
  o [s]
const map = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Array .isArray (xs) 
    ? xs .map (x => fn(x))
    : Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (xs) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)]))
const pluck = pipe (prop, map)
const sum = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => a + x, 0)
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a [k] = a [k] || []), (a[k] .push (x)), a), 
    {}
  )

const extract = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('proc_nm')),
  map (groupBy (prop ('status'))),
  map (map (pluck ('count'))),
  map (map (sum))
) 

const data = [{proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 26, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 73, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "fatal"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 34, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "success"}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The important thing is how simple we can make our custom `extract` function by using simple reusable helpers.

### Update

Note that a custom solution is not overly difficult:

```js
const extract = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => {
    const g = a [x .proc_nm] || {}
    const s = (g [x .status] || 0) + x .count
    g [x .status] = s
    a [x .proc_nm] = g
    return a
  }, {})

const data = [{proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 00: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 26, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 73, date: "2021-11-04 01: 00: 00", status: "success"}, {proc_nm: "ana-json-to-parquet", count: 50, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "warning"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 2, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "fatal"}, {proc_nm: "ana-foobar", count: 34, date: "2021-11-04 02: 00: 00", status: "success"}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

I find this harder to read and a bit tedious, but it's not horrible.